# Symfony2 Prevent Clicking Back

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have a store in my Symfony2 app and I want to keep the customer from clicking back once they get to a certain point in the ordering process. Not to actually prevent them from clicking the back button, mind you, but to invalidate the action of clicking back.

I've put the following in one of my controller functions:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);

return $this->render('myStoreBundle:Store:checkout.html.twig', $viewData, $response);
```

I've checked the headers on the store page using the network profiler in Chrome and they appear to have been correctly set. Is there something else I need to do to achieve the desired goal or is this not how you do what I'd like to have happen.

Comment: Why don't you handle it by javascript in the twig file of the page you are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly my first thought would be to use a session variable.

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

blocked part:

```
if ($session->has('block'))
{
    $this->redirect('certain_route_name');
}
```

certain part:

```
$session->set('block', 1);
```

finish the process:

```
$session->remove('block');
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question but this works too.

Comment: And that is what matters... :P